# use Jinq for hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8

I would like to be able to write linq-style specific queries in java using jinq (http://www.jinq.org/index.html) and the java 8 streams. However, in the set-up section it says you need to use the JPA entityManagerFactory (http://www.jinq.org/docs/queries.html#N65755). In my project I am using hibernate and the sessionFactory. Does that mean that I cannot use jinq at all or there's some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple viewing of the javadoc for "JINQ" shows very clearly that they take in a JPA "EMF", so you have to use JPA to use it.

I see no downside of using JPA. You can easily enough dip in to vendor specifics when you really need to and still use JPA for the majority